# Refresh problem in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, asp-classic

In my asp page there is one textbox name "ProductName"

if i write any thing in that textbox and refresh that page , textbox is not clear in firefox. But i open this same page in Internet explore and write any thing in textbox and refresh the page, my textbox comes clear

why textbox not comes clear in FireFox?

This is the html code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="ProductName" name="ProductName" style="width:235; height:20" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature of Firefox (one I'm quite fond of). There's nothing you can do about it on the server-side.

**EDIT:**

The longer version: There is something you can do about, but it's very messy. Basically, the way Firefox implements this is it refills in form elements with the same name when the user hits the refresh button.

The workaround is to change the `name` attribute on your HTML form elements every time the page loads. How you keep track of what you change them too is left to your discretion, but let me just say that as a Firefox user myself, having a website do this would annoy me no end.

Comment: The other workaround is the `autocomplete="off"` attribute, yes?

Comment: I found a server-side solution. PHP `session_start()` clears input data. Tested on firefox 103.0.2.

Answer (score 6):

"Actually firefox is stupid that way." - yes it is.

Another way would be to set autocomplete="off" on the input

Answer (score 4):

Firefox isn't stupid that way. That's appropriate behavior because presumably the div your fading in occurs on an event e.g. onclick, onchange, etc. And since that event isn't triggered on refresh firefox has no reason to show your div. It's your responsibility to write the js necessary to trigger events onload or when document is ready.

Back to topic: a simple solution is to set the autocomplete attribute of your form to 'off'

That's it.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the input as shown below and it should fix the issue.

```
<input type="text" id="ProductName" name="ProductName" style="width:235; height:20" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: To complete this answer, it's possible to put this attribute also on the whole form: 
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
[...]
</form>
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score 3):

Actually firefox is stupid that way. Let's say you have a checkbox and when the user clicks to activate that checkbox there is a div that should fade in. The problem here is that if you refresh the page your checkbox will remain active but your div will be hidden. They(firefox) did not think it all the way through and that is .. well stupid. Because of that you have to resort to js workarounds which (I'm not quite fond of).

I do agree that you need to have, at some poin, the same value inside some input, like when you submit a page, there is an error and you need to redirect the user back to the page containing the form. Then yeah!, ok!, you need the values... but to keep the values on refresh , well that s just stupid.

What user enters his details and then just thinks "hm I'll just press f5 now see what happens". If that's the kind of user 'roaming round' your site, please shut it down it's infested with stupidity

Ok so now that that is out of the way.

"change the name attribute on your HTML form elements every time the page loads"
this is a bad idea don`t do this...

instead you can use a js function that simply gets the input and sets the value to ""

```
onpageload:
document.getElementById('inp1').value = '';
document.getElementById('inp2').value = '';
document.getElementById('inp3').value = '';
```

and so on and so forth.
P.S. this is just an example, it's your job to see, what fits for you (be it jquery, prot or whatever); to see if you use a for loop or not; etc

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with the idea that firefox's behavior is "stupid".  It's unexpected, doesn't act like the other browsers, and is basically uncontrollable by the website owner.  None of which is a good thing.

Comment: rant aside, this isn't 'stupid'. Accidents happen. It's happened to me at least once. If your form is brittle, that's your fault, not the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

[`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) instances inherit a [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) method.

It can be used to clear all forms to its default values:

```
for(var i=0; i<document.forms.length; ++i)
    document.forms[i].reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

for this problem add

```
autocomplete="off"
```

attr to input tag for example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="ProductName" name="ProductName" style="width:235; height:20" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Ctrl+Shift+R** command to force reload (not from cache) (see Page Navigation Shortcuts on http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/moz_shortcuts.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Server-side solution:

PHP `session_start()` clears input data. Tested on firefox 103.0.2.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>


<input type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<select>
    <option>Choice 1</option>
    <option>Choice 2</option>
    <option>Choice 3</option>
    <option>Choice 4</option>
</select>
```