# How to clear form data on refresh of age in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I am writing a web page with a form on it but when I refresh the page the form does not clear the data like I want it to, this only happens in Firefox. Does anyone know how to get around this aside from using JQuery to go through and clear the forms for me?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refresh problem in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310798/refresh-problem-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) instances inherit a [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) method.

You can use it like

```
for(var i=0; i<document.forms.length; ++i)
    document.forms[i].reset();
```

Comment: would this apply to all forms on my page? do I need to change it to modify specific forms like document.myForm[i].reset()? I copied and pasted this into my document.ready JQ and it didn't seem it work

Comment: scratch that, it worked I was doing something wrong, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Its one of the default feature of Firefox.

Please reference this URL:

[Refresh problem in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310798/refresh-problem-in-firefox)